# React Router paths not correct?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to build some routes using react router v5 and basically I have a layout(Dashboard and this dashboard has some routes.) so if I do '/dashboard' it doesn't work'. the '/dashboard' comes from the routes that I map at the last piece of code, which is basically inside the AppContent which is the layout not sure what I am missing here...

my App.js file

```
<Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/"
                            name="Home"
                            render={(props) => <DefaultLayout {...props} />}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/login"
                            name="Login Page"
                            render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/register"
                            name="Register Page"
                            render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
                        />

                        <Route
                            path="*"
                            name="Page 404"
                            render={(props) => <Page404 {...props} />}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>

    my DefaultLayout File:


 <div>
            <AppSidebar />
            <div className="wrapper d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-light">
                <AppHeader />
                <div className="body flex-grow-1 px-3">
                    <AppContent />
                </div>
                {/* <AppFooter /> */}
            </div>
        </div>

my AppContentFile:

    <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map(
                            (route) =>
                                route.component && (
                                    <Route
                                        key={route.name}
                                        path={route.path}
                                        exact={route.exact}
                                        name={route.name}
                                        render={(props) => (
                                            <route.component {...props} />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                )
                        )}
                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your AppContentFile you need to correct your redirect from "/" to "/dashboard", just fixed like this:

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
```

after that add exact to this routes:

```
<Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
<Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page"
render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}/>
```

and add this route:

```
<Route path="/dashboard" exact name="Dashboard" render={(props) => 
<DefaultLayout {...props} />}/>
```

Comment: Thank you Aous, I did but it haa weird behavior now. So once I go to homepage('/') is fine it redirects to ('/dashboard'), then once I go to any other page is working, BUT when I manually go back to '/dashboard' ti shows the error page.

Comment: I think the problem is from the first router try to remove exact prop from "/" route then try it, if it's fail try to remove the router with path "*" and let me know to edit the answer.

Comment: When I remove the router path "*"  then the login or register routes are a blank page, when I remove the exact from '/' and the  "*"  then the route '/dashboard' works but login or register is blank. Now when I put back the exact and I remove the  "*" the result is: routes work fine but if I manually type '/dashboard' gives blank page

Comment: I have edit it check it again!

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The `exact` prop on the home `"/"` path necessarily precludes it from matching any nested route paths. In other words, when the path is `"/dashboard"` it now no longer *exactly* matches `"/"` and the layout component rendering the content is unmounted, unmounting any potential routes. It should be removed.

You also only need a single router component to provide a routing context for the entire app, so remove the extraneous `Router` in `AppContent`.

Recall also the within a `Switch` component that path order and specificity matters, so order your paths from more specific to less specific.

App

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register} />
    <Route
      path="/" // <-- can now match sub-routes
      name="Home"
      component={DefaultLayout}
    />
    <Route name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

AppContent - remove the `Router`

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map((route) =>
    route.component && (
      <Route
        key={route.name}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        name={route.name}
        render={(props) => (
          <route.component {...props} />
        )}
      />
    )
  )}
  <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you Drew, all the routes are working now apart from the error page route :(...ohh dear...

Comment: @vickyvasilopoulou Yeah.... using `"/"` as your "generic" path into subroutes will preclude anything being unmatched since `"/"` matches all routes universally. You *could* render a `Page404` as the last route in the nested switch instead of redirecting to `"/"`, or place the `AppContent` stuff on a nested path, i.e. `<Route path="/home" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />` which would allow the `"*"` 404 page to be matched and rendered as a catch all.